# Indexing in sphinx

Tags: c#, windows-services, sphinx

I have a problem in indexing in sphinx.
We have a database (MSSQL) that every second several records added into that.
I created a service (windows service) in C# that indexes new records every 20 seconds (delta).
This service merge delta with another index file every 15 (or 20) minutes.
I tested everything in everywhere and my service and sphinx work fine.
But, my problem is when I start my service, that works for a few minute and after that, indexer did not work for 10 minutes, and again works!!!
What's the problem?!

Comment: How long does the 'merge' itself take? Perhaps that is taking nearly 10 minutes.

Comment: No, always this merge is taking under 100 milliseconds. When indexer don't work merge is taking 1 - 1.2 second!

Comment: When indexer disable, i can't search and use Searchd.exe. I thought searchd.exe disabled but when i merged two index file manually, merging done successfully!

Comment: This windows service works in my laptop but not work in windows server! I created windows application of this windows service. This app worked in windows server but service not works );